# GStreamer assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, object-detection, yolo

I was trying to run this [repo](https://github.com/bendidi/Tracking-with-darkflow) to implement YOLO with Darkflow but I came into this strange error (stack below). I have reinstalled tensorflow and other packages like opencv and they are in place. There are also very little information about it on internet. Any idea regarding this issue is highly appreciated.

```
(python3:7151): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: cannot link elements
) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file /home/strange/software/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 1466
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "run.py", line 31, in <module>
   tfnet.camera()
 File "/home/strange/objectTracking/Tracking-with-darkflow/darkflow/darkflow/net/help.py", line 130, in camera
   'output_{}'.format(file), fourcc, fps, (width, height))
cv2.error: /home/strange/software/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1466: error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot link elements
in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open
```

Comment: This was quite persistent so I had to find a workaround and could never solve this. Finally I used ffmpeg instead which is super useful for basic video jobs.